# not able to log nihibernate sql (info,debug,error ) messages

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I want to log debug ,info and error message of Nhibernate.SQL. I am not able to log all the messages.

Can i use config as below?

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
```

or do I need to use as below?

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <level value="INFO" />
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level supplied to a logger is the *minimum* level to log, so you just need this to log DEBUG or above:

```
logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

Note that this will also log any WARN or FATAL log entries.